# Vim: Shortcut automatically inserted method, don't know how to replicate

Tags: vim

I stumbled upon something in Vim that I'm not quite sure how I can replicate.

Basically I have this

```
var first_set = input[0].split(',');
var second_set = input[1];
```

I had my cursor somewhere between the `]` and `;` on the second line, accidentally fat-fingered a key near `i` on my keyboard, and it instantly popped out what I was going to type.

```
var second_set = input[1].split(',');
```

I had previously inserted `.split(',')` to the first line.

Is there a Vim shortcut that automatically takes your last edit and spits it back out? I really can't figure out what Vim did that would know I wanted the exact same method. Even my autocomplete `<C-n>` doesn't go that far to even put in the same arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this isn't too obvious but you can use the `.` command to repeat the last command you did, also if you had deleted some piece of text then `p` would paste it. If this is an action that you do often you can create a macro that would automaticly transform something like `input[1]` into `iniput[1].split(',')`. Also you can use a snippets plugin to expand things like `spl` into what you want.

There's many options :).

Comment: This sounds like a `.`, yes.

Comment: Hmm. I think it might have been `p`. I could have had `.split(',')` as my last deleted piece of text. It's the only explanation I can think of given the situation I was in. Thanks for telling me about `.` though.